# trying to make a function of 2 strings combined into a new one

Tags: c, string

Is the code fine? When I use `puts(nstr)` in the function I do get the right result , but when on `main` all I get is "riends" output.
using a Microsoft Visual C++ Express if it helps.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<malloc.h>

char* strcpy2 (char* str1, char* str2)
{
    char nstr[20];
    int i,j;
    for (i = 0; str1[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        nstr[i] = str1[i];
    }
    for (j = i, i = 0; str2[i]!='\0'; i++, j++)
    {
        nstr[j] = str2[i];
    }
    nstr[j] = '\0';
    return nstr;
}

void main()
{
    char str1[10] = "Hello";
    char str2[10] = ",friends";
    puts(strcpy2(str1, str2));
}
```

Comment: You should not return a local (non-static) variable. Read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441218/can-a-local-variables-memory-be-accessed-outside-its-scope).

Comment: Declare nstr[20] in main and pass it in to strcpy2 as the third param

Comment: right name should be `strcat2`

Comment: The main problem is declaring "char nstr[20]" as a local variable, then passing it outside the function.  That's a huge "no-no".  A better solution is to declare the buffer *outside* of your function, then pass it in as a parameter.  Another problem is the implicit maximum of "20".  A better solution is to pass "max size" as a parameter, too.  Then modify your loop so it cannot exceed max size.

Comment: yeah but the point was to use only 2 parameters which are the strings , thanks !

Comment: `void main(){}` should be at least `int main(void){}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`nstr` is local to function `strcpy2`. Returning pointer to automatic local variable invokes undefined behavior. Change it to

```
static char nstr[20];
```

or use `malloc` to allocate memory dynamically.

Comment: works great, thanks. so that static thing makes the variable accessable out of the function? and why i dont need it when i use arrays?

Comment: @ItayZaguri; [Read this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/572550/2455888). *and why i dont need it when i use arrays?*: you mean dynamic allocation, right?

Comment: I think this answer is a bad hack. "It works" is not a good enough reason to use it, and as Martin already pointed out, it's not thread safe either. Also, now this function **cannot** work with any string longer than 19 chars (19 + 1 null). Therefore, it's not reusable at all.

Comment: @ray; *I think this answer is a bad hack.*: the answer shows that you cannot return a pointer to automatic local variable but `static` local variable. Dynamic allocation is also suggested. I am not gonna provide full code for that.  
*Also, now this function cannot work with any string longer than 19 chars (19 + 1 null). Therefore, it's not reusable at all.*: Its OP responsibility to generalize that function for any length of strings  and that's how he will learn.

Comment: @haccks: Your explanation does not change the situation. From this, the only deduction I can make is that the OP has learned to 'workaround' the issue by prefixing `static` on to variable names. I agree with you in not providing full code, but no one's asking for that either.

Comment: It's not thinking through the implications that gave us the wonder that is strtok()....:(

Comment: @MartinJames: True. There's no evidence here that the OP has any understanding about the consequences of his decision to use `static` here.

Answer (score 4):

## Summary

Welcome to SO. The main issue is that you're returning the address of a variable that has gone out of scope by the time you try to use it.

## Detail

When functions are invoked, local variables are pushed onto a *stack* (not the data structure!). Here, your local `nstr` array variable is pushed and is said to be defined within the function's scope.

However, when functions return, local variables are destroyed along with the stack on which they were placed. This means that your `nstr` variable, has already gone out of scope by the time your function has returned.

This causes your caller, `main` in this case, to end up with an *invalid* reference to memory that is no longer in use by the program, which can trigger all sorts of bugs and crashes.

Instead, you should pass a 3rd argument to your function so that it serves as the place where the new concatenated string will go. I don't think making the variable `static` here is necessary or a good idea. There's no need to keep something in memory when it shouldn't be.

## Updated Code

Based on this, your code should look more like this

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

void strcpy2 (char str1[], char str2[], char str3[])
{
    // ...
}

int main(void)
{
    char str1[10] = "Hello";
    char str2[10] = ",friends";
    char str3[20];
    strcpy2(str1, str2, str3);
    puts(str3);
    return 0;
}
```

You should be able to take it from here.

## Update - Why You Should Not Use `static` Here

Many have recommended using the `static` keyword here. I advice against this for the following reasons. Using `static` for your local variable causes your function to be:

1. ***Not* Thread-Safe:** `static` variables are *shared* variables;
2. ***Not* Reusable:** function breaks trying to use strings longer than your toy example with a cap of `19+1` chars including `null` and defeats the purpose of having a function in the first place;
3. ***Not* Memory Efficient:** the static variable will remain in memory with a string that no longer needs to be used until your program exits

You'd have a better-quality function if you pass the 3rd argument as a destination that already has enough space to contain the originals to be concatenated.

You could return a pointer that has been `malloc`'ed, *but* note that this is a bit more dangerous and will require more care from everyone using your function. For example, it must be unambiguously clear to every client that it's now *their* responsibility to `free` the memory returned by your function. This can be more error-prone because the `malloc`s are not immediately *visible* to those using it.  (Forgot to `free` your function's internal/invisible `malloc`? Whoops! Hello memory leak!).

Using the 3rd param should be safer in general.

You should really take the time to *understand* the side-effects and consequences that follow from decisions like these.

Comment: There is no `void main(){}` should be at least `int main(void){}` and your code should check if `str1` is long enough to satisfy `str2` and `str3`

Comment: @Michi: Good catch. It was from the OP's original code paste. Fixed to `int main` and to `return 0`

Comment: you got your `+1` :D. Any way change `int main(){}` void to `int main(void){}`

Comment: Since `C99` there is no need of `return 0;` because it is implicit, but we do not know which and where it will be used this code. Me, I never ignore things which are optional. in `C89` for example is not optional.

Comment: @Michi: I'd like to think that someone learning C *today* would at least be trying to use `C11` :) I also like to be a bit more explicit most of the time.

Answer (score 2):

The way you're doing this will not work. For one thing your variable nstr is locally defined and it will not be any good after you exit the function. I could show you how, but I'm guessing you're a student and need to hit the books a little harder. You can do this, it ain't that hard.

Answer (score 0):

I think a pointer with `malloc` will do the job here, try this:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

char *strcpy2 (char *str1, char *str2){
    char *result;
    size_t length = 0,i,j;

    length = strlen(str1) + strlen(str2);
    result = malloc(length + 1);

    for (i = 0; str1[i] != '\0'; i++){
        result[i] = str1[i];
    }

    for (j = i, i = 0; str2[i]!='\0'; i++, j++){
        result[j] = str2[i];
    }

    result[j] = '\0';
    return result;
}

int main(void){
    char str1[10] = "Hello";
    char str2[10] = ",friends";

    char *res = strcpy2(str1, str2);
    printf("%s\n",res);

    free(res);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

> Hello,friends

Answer (score -2):

if you print it using  printf("%s", strcpy2(str1, str2)); it will be fine.
I dont know whats wrong with puts

Comment: What you try looks like it works but this is only by chance, the code is incorrect as you try to access already deallocated memory. This is *undefined behaviour.* In C, something seemingly yielding the right result doesn't mean it's correct.

Comment: No. I don't need to compile your faulty code to spot undefined behaviour. You completely miss what's wrong with OPs code.

Comment: "I don't know what's wrong with `puts`". You should tell your professor your compiler is broken :)